# change "return"/"Go" key to "Next" on IOS using javascript and HTML

Tags: jquery, html, ios, ipad, safari

What I want to do is that change he return key to next key on iPad for my HTML form I have tried

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input").not( $(":button") ).keypress(function (evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
        iname = $(this).val();
        if (iname !== 'Submit'){
        var fields = $(this).parents('form:eq(0),body').find('button, input, textarea, select');
        console.log(fields);
        var index = fields.index( this );
        if ( index > -1 && ( index + 1 ) < fields.length ) {
            var id = fields.eq( index + 1 ).attr("id")
            alert("document");
            document.getElementById(id).focus();
            alert("without 0");
            $("#"+id)[0].focus();
            $("#"+id)[0].click();
            alert("with 0");
            $("#"+id)[0].focus();
        }
        return false;
        }
        }
        });
    });
```

But this doesn't works on iPad I read that apple doesn't opens up keyboard by focus or click event of jquery to avoid popping up keybord every now and then without proper interaction (tap of touch) of user. other wise this works properly in browser.

and this also had Go button instead of "Next" what I want is that when ever user clicks the Next key it should focus the next input field of my form

I have also tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var focused = $('input:first'); //this is just to have a starting point
        $(document).keypress( function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {e.preventDefault();alert("keyPressed");
                focused.next('input').trigger('touchstart'); //trigger touchstart
            }
        });
        $('input').on('touchstart', function () {
            $(this).focus();
            focused = $(this);
        });
    });
```

But this work perfectly for the custom input button but doesn't works for Return/Go Button and I specifically want this functionality for Return/G button on iPad

Answer (score 0):

IOS/Safari only "accepts" the focus when inside a touch event handler. workaround could be, you can trigger a touch event and insert the .focus() inside it. something like this.

**Use:**

```
document.getElementById(id).trigger('touchstart'); 
            //or
$('#'+id).trigger('touchstart');
```

**Instead of:**

```
document.getElementById(id).focus();
```

**Touchstart event-**

```
$('input').on('touchstart', function () {
    $(this).focus();   // inside this function the focus works
    focused = $(this); 
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EbU6a/)**

Comment: Thanks but I want to apply this on Go button of keyboard. Your code works perfectly for input type button but is not suitable for Go button Secondly I also want to change the label of Go button to Next.

Comment: Yes even on tab it works perfectly for input type="button" but doesn't works for enter key